# Where to find AppId in new Windows Dev Center

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-store, windows-phone-store, windows-dev-center

I'm **unable to find `AppId`** for any specific App, **on new "Windows Dev Center"** Dashboard. I need that AppId to add in my "WMAppManifest.xml" file **in order to fetch all of my In-App Products (IAPs)** from store for that specific App.

I used to **find that AppId easily in previous "Windows Phone Dev Center"** (which don't exist anymore). Here is the image which shows the location AppId in old Windows Phone Dev Center.

[image: Old Windows Phone Dev Center - AppId location]

since last two-three months, "Windows Store" & "Windows Phone Store" combined into one unified "Windows Dev Center" (which I actually don't like).

The App I've published is a Windows phone 8.0 app so I've published XAP package which successfully published as BETA. I've also successfully added 2 IAP for that App.

Can anybody tell me **where to find this AppId in new Windows Dev Center**.

Answer (score 1):

I found it here:
Select app in dashboard -> App management -> App identity ->
At the bottom of the page there are links for finding your app in the Store. In one I can see appid :)
[image: app id]

Comment: this is not available now, please guide where to find it right now.